# MvcJqgrid missing cellEdit option

Tags: mvcjqgrid

MvcJqGrid is a html helper for ASP.NET MVC

I can't see '**cellEdit**', '**cellsubmit**', '**cellurl**' option in MvcJqgrid.dll

Is there exists this setting option?

I want to use Cell Editing function in listing data.

Answer (score 1):

No, these options have not yet been implemented in MvcJqGrid. To be honest, editing capabilities are very minimal in MvcJqGrid. We are planning to expand on those features in the future.

Comment: Cell editing feature is very useful, wait to new version of MvcJqGrid.
Thanks for your answer!